# Error While Subscribing to Topic in SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Below error, I am getting while subscribing to the topic in Amazon SNS.

> Error: Not Authorized to publish internal endpoints.

Am Attaching the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use internal IP like 192.168.....

In your case: http://192.158.0.104:8080/NotificationsReceiver-1/NotificationsConsumerServlet

Following links might be of interest to read

[Publishing to Amazon SNS Topics from Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-vpc.html)
[Set up API Gateway Private Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html)

PS: IP was readable through black color overwriting ;) Next time copy/paste black image block rather than using brushes

Comment: Okay. Thanks @raevilman. I was thinking of using Amazon Virtual Private Cloud.Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: SNS itself is not "inside" your VPC, so the private addresses have no meaning to SNS.